# How CPU/chipset PCI-E lanes work and what's the difference?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, pci-express, chipset

I'm using heavily PCI-E-overloaded system with all available pci-e slots fully used. Intel specification of my i7-2600K declares support for only 16 pci-e lanes, yet despite using lots of extension cards, still my 2 GPUs run at x8 speed. I thought due to other cards it'll be something like x4 or less.

So how system supports more than 16 pci-e lanes overall, despite CPU claiming support only for 16? This is my `lspci -vv` result:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
            LnkCap: Port #2, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM not supported, Exit Latency L0s <256ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
            LnkCap: Port #3, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM not supported, Exit Latency L0s <256ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
            LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
            LnkCap: Port #2, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
            LnkCap: Port #3, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
            LnkCap: Port #4, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
            LnkCap: Port #5, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
            LnkCap: Port #7, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
            LnkCap: Port #8, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation P67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 580] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <256ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <256ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF100GL [Quadro 4000] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
            LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <256ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
            LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <256ns, L1 <4us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
03:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9123 PCIe SATA 6.0 Gb/s controller (rev 11) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
03:00.1 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE912x IDE Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
05:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9123 PCIe SATA 6.0 Gb/s controller (rev 11) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
05:00.1 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE912x IDE Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
06:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362 SATA Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <16us
            LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
07:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
08:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
09:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
09:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev c0) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
0a:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
            LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
```

I see that there are some ports that belong to CPU itself and some x1 slots that are supported by Chipset. What is difference between chipset-backed pci-e lanes and CPU-backed ones?

Here is `lspci -t`:

```
  -[0000:00]-+-00.0
             +-01.0-[01]--+-00.0
             |            \-00.1
             +-01.1-[02]--+-00.0
             |            \-00.1
             +-16.0
             +-19.0
             +-1a.0
             +-1b.0
             +-1c.0-[03]--+-00.0
             |            \-00.1
             +-1c.1-[04]----00.0
             +-1c.2-[05]--+-00.0
             |            \-00.1
             +-1c.3-[06]----00.0
             +-1c.4-[07]----00.0
             +-1c.6-[08-09]----00.0-[09]--+-00.0
             |                            \-01.0
             +-1c.7-[0a]----00.0
             +-1d.0
             +-1f.0
             +-1f.2
             \-1f.3
```

I noticed that Threadrippter CPUs have 64 pci-e lanes support but motherboards tend to expose only 48 via pci-e slots on motherboard. Does it mean that X399 doesn't use such approach and here all those "additional" pci-e lanes like M.2 etc. are also supported directly by CPU?

Comment: You CPU probably has 16 lanes, but your motherboard PCH might have more.

Comment: Try `lspci -t` to see the tree structure. I see two PCI bridges, one with 2x width 8 ports, and one with 8x width 1 ports. So that would be 24 PCIe lanes in total ... not sure how they map to the 16 PCIe lanes your chipset is supposed to have.

Comment: @Mokubai Added `-t` What is functional difference between PCH pci-e lanes and CPU ones? Do they have different features in temrs of memory access or something like that? Different performance?

Comment: Some will be full speed to the PCH, and some will be full speed to the CPU. Any other routing will be slower.

Comment: The ones on the CPU will be closer to the memory controller which is on the CPU. Also being on the CPU they may have a few microseconds faster latency. I wouldn't expect it to make any significant performance difference.